# Decrypt password in SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY Asym_EPassword  
WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_512 
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = testdemo123
```

I have encrypted a `Password` column of my table with the above encryption asymmetric key.

Now I want to decrypt the `password` column inside my `select` query

Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: You're not meant to decrypt passwords. You're meant to encrypt strings to be tested against the encrypted value stored in the database. If something can be decrypted there's no point encrypting it, it wouldn't be secure.

Comment: While I agree you shouldn't decrypt passwords. I think the last statement "if something can be decrypted theres no point encrypting it" is slightly wrong. Encryption should be reversible, where as hashing is a one way mechanism.

Comment: i am just asking to retrieve decrypted password in select query not to save in database

Comment: can you please suggest how to match a normal string password with encrypted password in database

Comment: You're right @Darren, in this context the password should be hashed and not encrypted. Assuming the OP is not storing passwords for other applications?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), 
    DecryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('Asym_EPassword'),
    YourColumn, 'testdemo123')) AS PlainText
FROM YourTable;
```

SQLFiddle don't let users create asymmetric keys, so for demo copy/paste this to your own SSMS:

```
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY Asym_EPassword
WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_512 
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'testDemo123!'

DECLARE @PlainText NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @CipherText VARBINARY(MAX)

SET @PlainText = 'AAAAA'
SELECT @CipherText = EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('Asym_EPassword'), @PlainText);

SELECT @CipherText;

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), DecryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('Asym_EPassword'), @CipherText, N'testDemo123!'));
```

Comment: i have used the same query but plaintext field has null value

Comment: @user1826753 Check if you wrote the key name correctly and are you sure data is encrypted with this key?